# Align pictures horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to get my pictures horizontal. I am using bootstrap and emmet. I have tried floats and display. Here's my code:

```
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="bottombanner">
                    <col-sm-3><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://www.worldmapsonline.com/images/murals/mercator_classic_world_political_wall_mural_lg.jpg" alt=""></col-sm-3>
                    <col-sm-3><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt=""></col-sm-3>
                    <col-sm-3><img src="" alt=""></col-sm-3>
                    <col-sm-3><img src="" alt=""></col-sm-3>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And then here is my CSS:

```
.bottombanner {
max-width: 20%;
max-height: auto;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

I have tried it with both and one or the other for float and display but to no avail.

I have also tried with and without the div container just to see. I also tried using the bootstrap img-responsive, but it didn't seem to have an effect, I took it off because I think I remember that img-responsive auto-centers?

Comment: I've not used emmet before - does that do something with `<col-sm-3>`? Seems to work fine if you use divs there. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owJYLZ

Comment: the col-sm-3 is the bootstraps kind of way of defining space. Here is a link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp explaining it cause I will do a terrible job for sure, it's short and straight forward. I can get it to work with text, but I simply cannot get it working with my images for whatever reason.

Comment: Haha, I know `.col-sm-3` is how bootstrap uses columns, but it's `<div class="col-sm-3">`, not `<col-sm-3>`.... that's why I'm asking you what you're doing with those elements. Is that on purpose or is that a mistake?
 did you see the link I pasted?

Comment: Ahhhhh haha thanks so  much! You were of course absolutely right. Rookie mistake on my part, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bottombanner">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://www.worldmapsonline.com/images/murals/mercator_classic_world_political_wall_mural_lg.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><img src="" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><img src="" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use `col-sm-3` as a class. And since you set width as 20% in `bottombanner`, your images will be very small in size.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was a simple mistake on my part haha. Whoops! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What is the `<col-sm-3>` is it a div or what?

One easy way could be to horizontal align your images is to emulate table display property.

```
.bottombanner {
    display: table;
}

.col-sm-3 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this should get your images horizontal aligned to each other.

Comment: the col-sm-3 is the bootstraps kind of way of defining space. Here is a link: w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp explaining it cause I will do a terrible job for sure, it's short and straight forward. I can get it to work with text, but I simply cannot get it working with my images for whatever reason. I would like to try and figure out how to get it working with the column system, as I dont understand tables just yet.

Comment: actually you dont use tables, but yes you mimic the table behaviour, in css (pre flexbox) __*you cant horizontal align items inside of divs unless you utilize the table behaviour.*__ with flexbox this can be done, but i dont think flexbox first of all is ready for production, second you should really get the hang of plain css before start experimenting with new and flashy css.